# Why are the "Project Defaults" settings in VS 2019 missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I can't find the Project Defaults settings in Visual Studio 2019. I saw them in pictures or YouTube videos, but I can't find them in my Visual Studio Configuration Properties.

[image: http://prntscr.com/oa01l5]

I have already Googled for this issue, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Create a new project and compare?

Comment: I tried and it does not work.

Comment: I've always known the most recent VS versions to be buggy until like two years after release. So it could just be a bug.

Comment: Make sure you have the C++ workload installed, do a repair install, create a new project and then include the contents of the *.vcxproj file in your question

Answer (score 1):

Project Defaults setting items moved to other categories.

For example, "Configuration Type" option was placed Genernal > Project Defaults category. But, you can see it in the General > General properties as like you posted image.

The most options have moved to General > Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this may be a little late:

Make sure that Visual Studio 2019 is installed with the same language as other already installed Visual Studio versions. Otherwise, incorrect project setting dialogs can occur, for example.

Comment: I installed Visual studio in a new laptop with english but still I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the C/C++ > All Options (second to last) you can find what you are looking for; in my case it was Additional include directories.
[image]

Comment: I don't see what i was looking for. Any other ideas?
In my case, i'm looking for the "Character Set"

EDIT: nevermind, it was in Advanced

Comment: I just double checked,  the "All Options" section has "All Options" even those in Advanced. If the question is answered please mark the answer accepted.